# Different Only-If Condition as Guard for Chef

Tags: ruby, scripting, chef-infra, chef-recipe, guard

Is there a way to use this script (or something which looks approximately the same) as a only_if guard in chef?

```
#!/bin/bash
application = application_name
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then  *do something*
fi
```

I tried the classic way but it either returns nothing so the only_if condition passes by default or it tells me that I can't compare a string with an integer (which is obvious).

```
execute "script" do
command "my command here"
only_if "$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep service_name | wc -l) > 0"
```

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To convert it literally you would need to use the `test` command, usually aliased as `[`: `only_if "[ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep service_name | wc -l) > 0 ]"`. But you could also do it somewhat more nicely in Ruby code instead:

```
only_if { shell_out!('ps -ef').include?('service_name') }
```

Comment: Hello, the test command works just fine, thank you very much. However when I try the second piece of code I recieve this error:                                                                    "NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for #<Mixlib::ShellOut:0x00000005368008>"  Do I need to declare the method beforehand ?

Comment: shell_out("systemctl is-active #{service_name} --quiet").exitstatus == 0 [source](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/service/systemd.rb#L164)

Comment: If you are going that route, you can use the error? method to be a little more expressive. Either works.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question more generally, if you have an arbitrary script you want to use for your `only_if` or `not_if` guard, you can do something along these lines:

```
my_guard_script = File.join Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'my_guard_script.sh'

file my_guard_script do
  content <<- EOF
#!/bin/sh

# contents of your script here
EOF
end

resource 'my_awesome_resource' do
  some_parameter 'some_value'
  only_if my_guard_script
end
```

Warning: I haven't tested this, so there are probably bugs.